# Jump to anchor link within tabs with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, tabs, anchor, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to link to anchors within tabs from external pages using jQuery UI. It seems like the problem is that it creates two hashtags in the URL. How can I fix this?

Here is what I have so far: 
http://jsfiddle.net/3n2ux/

```
$(function () {
    var href = location.href;
    if (window.location.hash) {
        var split = href.split("#"); // split the string; usually there'll be only one # in an url so there'll be only two parts after the splitting
        location.hash = split[1];
    }
    window.location.href = split[0] + "#" + split[2];
});
```

Comment: SO the link will be any external page link?

Comment: Can you please explain more what is your requirement?

Comment: If you look at the link on the first tab, it should take you down to the h2 tag on Tab 2. The link on Tab 2, should take jump down to the h2 tag on Tab 1. I can get link to open the tab, it can't seem to find a way so that it opens that tab then jumps down to the right location.